# How to setup a dblink from Oracle 10gR2 on Linux RedHat 64bit to Postgresql 8.3 on Linux RedHat 64bit too?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, dblink

I try this query from Oracle :

```
select * from "a_table"@Postgres;
```

Here is the error message I get :

```
ORA-28545: error diagnosed by Net8 when connecting to an agent
Unable to retrieve text of NETWORK/NCR message 65535
ORA-02063: précédant 2 lines de RECORD
28545. 0000 -  "error diagnosed by Net8 when connecting to an agent"
*Cause:    An attempt to call an external procedure or to issue SQL
       to a non-Oracle system on a Heterogeneous Services database link
       failed at connection initialization.  The error diagnosed
       by Net8 NCR software is reported separately.
*Action:   Refer to the Net8 NCRO error message.  If this isn't clear,
       check connection administrative setup in tnsnames.ora
       and listener.ora for the service associated with the
       Heterogeneous Services database link being used, or with
       'extproc_connection_data' for an external procedure call.
Erreur à la ligne 1, colonne 25
```

Here is **tnsnames.ora**

```
Postgres =
   (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
   )
   (CONNECT_DATA =
     (SID = RECORD)
   )
   (HS=OK)
  )
```

Here is **listener.ora**

```
LISTENER_HS =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1525))
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = PNPKEY))
      )
    )
  )

SID_LIST_LISTENER_HS =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = RECORD)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /oracle/product/10.2.0)
      (PROGRAM = hsodbc)
      (ENVS = "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/oracle/product/10.2.0/lib32:/oracle/product/10.2.0/hs/lib32:/user/lib")
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /oracle/product/10.2.0)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )
```

Note after starting the listener, here is the output

```
$ lsnrctl status LISTENER_HS

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 10.2.0.3.0 - Production on 22-FEB-2012 13:45:09

Copyright (c) 1991, 2006, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1525)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER_HS
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 10.2.0.3.0 - Production
Start Date                22-FEB-2012 13:45:05
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 3 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      ON
Listener Parameter File   /oracle/product/10.2.0/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /oracle/product/10.2.0/network/log/listener_hs.log
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1525)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=PNPKEY)))
Services Summary...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "RECORD" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "RECORD", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Here **initPostgres.ora**

```
HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO = Postgres
HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL = DEBUG
HS_FDS_TRACE_FILE_NAME = /oracle/product/10.2.0/hs/log/postgres.trc
HS_FDS_SHAREABLE_NAME = /usr/lib/psqlodbc.so

set ODBCINI= /etc/odbc.ini
```

`/oracle/product/10.2.0/hs/log/record.trc` is empty.

What am I missing ?

Oracle 10gR2
Linux RedHat 64bit

Postgresql 8.3
Linux RedHat 64bit

**EDIT:**
When I try to check manually that the ODBC driver is up and running, this is what I get :

```
$ isql postgres USER PASS -v
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib/psqlodbc.so' : /usr/lib/psqlodbc.so: Ne peut ouvrir le fichier d'objet partagé: Aucun fichier ou répertoire de ce type
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have asked the same question on Oracle forum and I get a response.

Simply, I can't use `hsodbc` on Linux 64bit there is no port from Linux 32bit.
Instead, I must use `DG4ODBC` incompatibe with my Oracle 10.2.0.3.
Then my alternatives are either :

- install Database Gateway for ODBC 11.2.0.3
- migrate from Oracle 10.2.0.3 to Oracle 10.2.0.4 or greater
- or apply the patch 5965763

Detailed reponse is [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2350192&tstart=0).